# C# HtmlAgilityPack Refresh the value

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Since a while I'm coding in C# and I'm trying to create a couple of small tools for myself and my friends but I've ran into a problem, which stops me from continuing.

The problem is this. I want to use HmtlAgilityPack to get a changing value to use it for a couple of diffrent actions. But the problem is, that the value gets stuck on the same value until I restart the program.

So here is the code I'm using:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running the program!");
        Console.WriteLine("Reading the value!");
        int i = 0;
        string url = "Website";
        while (i < 300)
        {
            i++;
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument LoadWebsite = web.Load(url);
            HtmlNode rateNode = LoadWebsite.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='the-value']");
            string rate = rateNode.InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine(i + ". " + rate);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

So here it first loads the website. Next it gets the value from div. After that it writes the value so I can check it. But it just keeps writing the same value.

My question here is, that I don't know what I have to change to get newest value because the value changes every few seconds and I need the most recent value from my website. It's like the value is needed to keep the system running.

Comment: After `Thread.Sleep`, clear everything i.e. `web=null`, `LoadWebsite=null` and check the next iteration whether it gives you the same record or not.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it hasn't changed or at least it didn't change as quick as it should. Maybe there is something that must be changed completely like loading another side first and then loading the first one again or to clean the cache of the program or something like that to get ride of the value.

Btw the value has changed but only like once in 2 minutes which is way to slow

Comment: Though unrelated of what you ask, you can use `Timer` instead of sleeping the main thread which causes not responding status in the application.

Comment: I can try but that still won't solve my problem

Comment: Does someone got any other idea on what I could try next?

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();` outside the loop, it isn't necessary to create for every loop.
You could be having caching issues in the website that you want to crawl.

Set `web.UsingCache = false;`.

If it doesn't work append some random string so that every call is different.

Code:

```
HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
htmlWeb.UsingCache = false;
int i = 0;
while (i < 300)
{
    var uri = new Uri($"yoururl?z={Guid.NewGuid()}");
    i++;
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument LoadWebsite = htmlWeb.Load(uri.AbsoluteUri);
    HtmlNode rateNode = LoadWebsite.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='the-value']");
    string rate = rateNode.InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine(i + ". " + rate);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: htmlWeb.UsingCache = false; doesn't work for me. I can use HtmlWeb but it doesn't find UsingCache then.
Or am I missing something I have to add first?

Comment: Which version of HttpAgilityPack are you using?

Comment: as far as I can see it is the most recently version available. Visual Studio says it's v4.0.30319
Oh and I am using the 4.5 Framework version if that's the one you want to know

Comment: I've updated my code; My HAP is the same as yours and UsingCache is available.

Comment: where have you downloaded it then? I've got mine from here http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/releases/view/90925

Comment: Via `Nuget` - Right click on your solution, click on `Manage Nuget Packages for Solution`, unninstall your version of HtmlAgilityPack, search for it via `Browse` and install it.

Comment: Well I've installed it on the classic way so I don't even know what that Magae Nuget Packages is :C
Sorry it's like a whole new thing for me

Comment: Well I've no clue why I can't use that function but here is what it looks like if that gives you any idea http://i.imgur.com/h88WaXC.png

Comment: Replace that first line with `HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();`

Comment: Oh now I got it. I missed the point that htmlweb is a var and not the HtmlWeb part.
Ok I will try out the part and see if it works

Comment: Well the command now works but it still keeps the same value. I think I also know where the problem is. I need to get the value as a number because I need compare the numbers to see if they are bigger or not.
Maybe there is a way to get the value as a number but I'm to stupid to find it. :C